# FLutter : Unhandled Exception: CameraException(INVALID_PATH, The platform "TargetPlatform.android"

Tags: android, flutter, video, camera, video-recording

I recently started flutter and in my project I have to record a video with timer.
I am getting this error when I click on stop button to stop the video recording.
I tried to display the path and I got the path

```
I/flutter (19037): Video recorded to /data/user/0/app.package/cache/REC8929992591965700575.mp4


I/flutter (19037): Error: INVALID_PATH
I/flutter (19037): Error Message: The platform "TargetPlatform.android" did not return a path while reporting success. The platform should always return a valid path or report an error.

I/flutter (21723): Video recorded to /data/user/0/app.package/cache/REC4634449859696013797.mp4
E/flutter (21723): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: CameraException(INVALID_PATH, The platform "TargetPlatform.android" did not return a path while reporting success. The platform should always return a valid path or report an error.)
```

using this plugin:

```
  camera: ^0.9.4+5
  video_player: ^2.2.10
```

my code :

```
 void _onStopButtonPressed() {
    if (cd.isRunning) { //timer
      cd.cancel();
    }
 _stopVideoRecording().then((file) {
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
      if (file != null) {
        videoPath = file; //getting the file
      }
     
    });
  }
Future<XFile> _stopVideoRecording() async {
    
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isRecordingVideo) {
      return null;
    }

    try {
     return controller.stopVideoRecording();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
      return null;
    }
   }
```

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72994

Answer (score -1):

I had the same situation and found a solution.

**Try to control your timer controller after stopping or starting recording, not before (Otherwise you will get the error)**

*Use like this:*

```
final file = await _controller?.stopVideoRecording();

  setState(() {
    _controller.reset();
    _isRecording = false;
  });
```

Comment: There is not `.reset()` for camera controller...